# Why in this case decltype behavior is different from normal expression with libstdc++?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, libstdc++

I found a case when expression inside `decltype` is processed successfully while the same expression outside `decltype` gives an error: [see on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/nKakza).

I'm checking if there is an overload of outputting into stream for a given type (`operator <<`) - by using `decltype` and type traits. But for libstdc++ from GCC < 7 `decltype` returns a correct type even for cases where there isn't such overload.

I tried Clang with libc++ - there is no such problem. Tried GCC 7.1 - no problem. But if I try GCC < 7 or Clang with libstdc++ from GCC < 7 - problem arise.

Basically:

```
class Foo {};

...

decltype(std::declval<std::ostringstream>() << std::declval<Foo>()) // gives std::ostringstream&

...

Foo foo;
std::ostringstream out;
out << foo; // gives an error (as it should, there is no overload for Foo)
```

So, why it's happening, what's wrong with libstdc++?

Comment: Which C++ version is using in each case? (if no forcing with --std= flag, which version is used by default?), maybe the response is different because different versions of C++ are used by default in each compiler.

Comment: [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FdJksT0DKbl91YXd) and [gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2yJHOCfCgNf1TASv) give opposite results on this example. So this seems to be a compiler bug perhaps?

Comment: As you can see on Godbolt, I'm using -std=c++14 flag for all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::declval<std::ostringstream&>() << std::declval<T const &>()
//                             ^                     ^^^^^^^^
```

Value categories matter. You are testing for the ability to stream a `const T` lvalue into a `ostringstream` lvalue.

In your original code, the `<<` resolves to the [until-recently-unconstrained](https://wg21.link/LWG2534) `<<` overload for rvalue streams. Without the constraint, the expression is always well-formed.

Comment: Could you please elaborate about "until-recently-unconstrained overload"? How it was unconstrained in libstdc++ (and constrained in libc++)?

Comment: Thanks! Strangely, it's not marked as complete in libc++ status: https://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html (but it works at least since clang 3.4)